# how to inject IBk(knn) inside j48 algorithm? (weka, java)

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I want to write a classifier based on j48 desicion tree in weka that uses another classification algorithm inside it at the leafs. specifically i want knn.

let's see a classification process for example: given a new instance i want to get to "his" leaf using the j48 tree and then instead of returning the class associated with that leaf, i want to return the classification that a knn algorithm will return on that instance, based on the training set instances that got to that leaf. 
so basically i want to inject knn algorithm inside the classify method of j48.

i'm looking for an easy "not-to-write-too-much" way to do that in java using weka API.
worst case scenario for me is to write my own desicion tree and implement it with knn.
best case scenario is if i can use j48 and IBk as black boxes and somehow make this "mixed" classifier.

love to hear any ideas on how to do it.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The classification of J48 is apparently not used once you reach the leave and after you performed k-NN. This leaves only the k-NN result, so as far as I can see you can just use k-NN without J48 to achieve the same results as the above described setup.